# If $S$ and $T$ are projections with $S\circ T \neq T\circ S$, then can $S\circ T$ ever be a projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, function-and-relation-composition

I'm looking to find out if $S$ and $T$ are projections with $S\circ T \neq T\circ S$, then can $S\circ T$ ever be a projection. If it can what is an example of it? If it can't how would I go about proving it?

Comment: Just to clarify, are these orthogonal projections? Or a general projection (i.e. satisfying $T^2 = T$)? Are we in finite-dimensional inner product space?

Comment: They are general projections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $W\leq V$ be any proper subspace and $W', W''\leq V$ two subspaces such that $V=W\oplus W'=W\oplus W''$. Let $T$ be the projection onto $W$ along $W'$ and $S$ the projection onto $W$ along $W''$. Then $TS=S$ and $ST=T$ are both projections, but $ST\neq TS$ since $\ker ST=W'$ and $\ker TS=W''$.

Can you construct an example $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Is it possible to get a counterexample where $S$, $T$ are orthogonal projectors, and $ST$, $TS$ are projectors, but not orthogonal?

Comment: No. In this case, after a change of basis, you may as well assume these are projections onto coordinate subspaces (use Gram-Schmidt to find the appropriate basis). Then, $ST=TS$ and $R(ST)=R(T)\cap R(S)$.